# Is there a topological group $G$ such that the $\pi_1(G)$ of this group is itself?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, fundamental-groups

I know that there is a correspondece between a group $G$ and the fundamental group of some Topological Space. But is there some non trivial exemple of a Topological Group $G$ such that $\pi_1(G) = G$?

Comment: Do you have a trivial example?

Comment: Fundamental groups of topological groups are abelian, so there aren't many candidates if you assume some condition like finite generation. Without that, I'm not sure; my intuition is that non-f.g. abelian groups are either terrible (e.g,. $\mathbb{Q}$) or trivial (e.g., $\mathbb{R}$) topologically.

Comment: It certainly cannot happen for, say, Lie groups, because their fundamental groups are countable.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43002/fundamental-groups-of-topological-groups